# How to get import X to import functions, classes etc, when constructing a package?

Tags: python, package, python-import, python-module, setup.py

When importing a popular library, for example `>>> import numpy`, and then `>>> help(numpy)`, tons of tons of classes and functions are made available.

This is the structure of my package:

```
Blur/
├── __init__.py
├── blur
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── blur.py
│   ├── funcs
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── funcs.py
│   ├── scripts
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── blur_script.py
│   ├── tests
│   └── utils
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── timer.py
└── setup.py
```

I do `>>> import blur` and then `>>> help(blur)`, I get this:

```
NAME
    blur

PACKAGE CONTENTS
    blur
    funcs (package)
    scripts (package)
    utils (package)

FILE
    /Users/admin/Documents/Studie/IN3110/assignment4/Blur/blur/__init__.py
```

I want `import blur` to import the blur.py module, with its functions and classes. If I want to import blur.py I have to write `import blur.blur`. Think it is a bit ugly, don't you think? How to do this with only `import blur`?

Comment: Have you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834/can-someone-explain-all-in-python)?

Comment: I am aware, but thats not what i am trying to do. From X import * is not safe due to possible namespace conflicts. Im trying to understand how libraries like numpy only require a simple "import numpy" for the module to be imported, not "import numpy.foo.thud.etc"

Comment: Check out [their \_\_init\_\_.py file](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/__init__.py) and see how they are importing numerous other things from within that. They are also using `__all__` and extending it with the `__all__` from some of those other imports which makes all of those functions available from the one import.

Comment: I thought `__all__ ` in the init.py files were invoked only when calling `from X import * `. Is this not true? What in the numpy-init-file makes it so that `import numpy` works? I am looking at it myself, but some guidance would help a lot.

Comment: I broke it out below as an answer @Snusifer

Answer (score 0):

So let's walk down a small portion of `numpy` that hopefully makes this more understandable.

numpy main `__init__.py` [code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/__init__.py)

```py
from . import polynomial
```

So that says to do a relative import (we know from the `.`) within the same folder, of `polynomial`. So in practice, this puts the module name into the namespace which we know by doing:

```py
>>> 'polynomial' in dir(numpy)
True
```

What ends up in the namespace is based on module names and top level packages for the most part. So in this case, with `numpy`, each of those imports is being brought in to make up the giant list of available functions/etc.

---

Look at all of these import statements:

```py
    from . import _distributor_init

    from . import core
    from .core import *
    from . import compat
    from . import lib
    # FIXME: why have numpy.lib if everything is imported here??
    from .lib import *

    from . import linalg
    from . import fft
    from . import polynomial
    from . import random
    from . import ctypeslib
    from . import ma
    from . import matrixlib as _mat
    from .matrixlib import *
    from .compat import long
```

And if you want you can go through and collect all of those names, plus everything within any `*` and you'll eventually add up to all of the available functions in `numpy`